# Bluetooth device removal not persisting

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I have a linked bluetooth device. I can select "remove device" and it disappears, but when I turn it off and on again it immediate reconnects.

I have also removed via `bluetoothctl` with the same problem:

```
$ bluetoothctl paired-devices
Device 38:EC:0D:87:65:DB AirPods Pro
$ bluetoothctl remove 38:EC:0D:87:65:DB
```

How can I permanently remove it?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 0):

From a terminal enter `bluetoothctl` this will list all bluetooth devices. For example:

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 00:C2:C6:BC:22:5C Pairable: yes
```

Next you must type `remove` and the ID of the controller `00:C2:C6:BC:22:5C`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I used `bluetoothctl paired-devices` to get the controller ID, which I then removed. The problem persists.